# 19:10 No sound after new install

Tags: system-installation, sound, mute

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my new PC and I notice there's no audio.

I read a lot of guides and solutions on Google but no one fits for me.

I have a "[MSI x570 gaming plus carbon pro wifi](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-X570-GAMING-PRO-CARBON-WIFI/Specification)"

Ask me for more details if needed. Any help? :)

Answer (score 1):

This will reload your sound drivers
`sudo alsa force-reload`
Now, reboot.
If this did not work for you, then try reinstalling PulseAudio:
`sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct audio Output Device selected in your 'Sound' settings.
If you have a graphics card with hdmi installed that will have an audio Output Device. Then you motherboard has it's own audio Output Device. In 'Show Applications'>'Settings' click the 'Sound' tab. In the 'Output' section make sure you have the correct 'Output Device' selected.